# Why is Sunday not Soleildi?

Tags: étymologie, indications-de-temps

Why is Sunday not `Soleildi`?
Why is it the only day that doesn't follow the Hellenistic naming convention?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is more a Latin language question as the change predates the French language emergence but nevertheless in Latin "**Sunday**" used to be named ***dies solis*** (day of the Sun), just like it is in English and many northern Europe languages.

This changed when [Emperor Constantine the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_the_Great), who converted to (or at least supported) Christianity, first decided *dies solis* to be the weekly day of rest on March the 7<sup>th</sup> 321 A.D. and then [Emperor Theodosius I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodosius_I) renamed it ***dies dominicus*** (day of the Lord) on Nov the 3<sup>rd</sup> 386 A.D.:

> *Solis die, quem dominicum rite dixere maiores* → Day of the Sun, more correctly named: of the Lord.

*Dies dominicus* gave the French ***dimanche*** although old French used ***diemaine*** from ***dies magnus*** (great day) for Sunday. Should this had not happened, Sunday would have likely been named ***"[soudi](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/des-jours-qui-se-suivent-sans-se-ressembler)"*** in French.

There is a similar difference affecting Saturday. This used to be the day of Saturn (*dies saturni*) but it was replaced by *dies sabbatum* then late Latin *sambati dies* after the Hebrew day of *Sabbath*. In romance languages, it is still named after it: fr. *samedi*, sp. & port. *sábado*, it. *sabato*, cat. & oc. *dissabte*, rom. *sâmbătă*… German has both *Samstag* "day of Sabbath" and *Sonnabend* = "Sunday eve", Russian has *cуббота* (subbóta) and Polish *sobota* which also refer to Sabbath.

It is worth noting that all romance languages followed the Theodosius rule (it. *dominica*, sp. *domingo*, cat. *dimenge*, rom. *dominica*, etc.). There was also later, in medieval Latin, an attempt to remove any reference to the remaining pagan divinities (Moon, Mars, Mercury, Jupiter, Venus) by renaming Monday *Feria Secunda* (second weekday), Tuesday *Feria Tertia* and so on until Friday *Feria Quinta*. Fortunately, this didn't survived except with Portuguese, where Monday is still *Segunda-feira*, Tuesday *Terça-feira*, up to Friday *Quinta-feira*.

Northern Europe languages have kept the sun reference for Sunday except in the gaelic area where this day is named [*Dé Domhnaigh*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/D%C3%A9_Domhnaigh) in Irish, [DiDomhnaich](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Did%C3%B2mhnaich) in Scottish and [Jedoonee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jedoonee) in Manx, all three based on *dies dominicus*.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently French isn't the only language that uses "day of the Lord".

To expand on jlliagre's answer, the pattern I've found with google translate is that southern languages closer to Latin use "day of the Lord" while northern languages with more Germanic influence retain "day of the Sun". Slavic languages seem to be using a different system entirely.

Languages that use "day of the Sun":

- English
- Welsh
- German
- Dutch
- Danish
- Finnish
- Swedish
- Norwegian

Languages that use "day of the Lord":

- French
- Spanish
- Catalan
- Portuguese
- Italian

Answer (score 1):

According to the etymology in [1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dimanche), *dimanche* comes from Latin *dies dominicu* meaning *the day of the Lord*.